# Sort Dynamic Object by DateTime c#

Tags: c#, windows, sorting

From an API response, I get a JArray result:

```
dynamic Backups = JArray.Parse(result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result.ToString());
```

Backups variable holds the result for me as dynamic. Here is an example of the result I get:

```
[{
    "bu_region": "US",
    "created_at": "2022-01-04 00:06:09",
    "is_automate": "0",
    "bu_snapshot_name": "null",
    "plugin_v": "4.5.2",
},
{
    "bu_region": "US",
    "created_at": "2022-02-20 00:07:55",
    "is_automate": "0",
    "bu_snapshot_name": "null",
    "plugin_v": "4.5.2",
},
{
    "bu_region": "US",
    "created_at": "2021-12-31 00:05:31",
    "is_automate": "0",
    "bu_snapshot_name": "null",
    "plugin_v": "4.5.2",
}]
```

I would like to sort the Dynamic Result above by DateTime, and then, I show the result in my form application,

On the form after adding the above result data to an Object, I can sort it using below code:

```
List<Cards> sortedListByDate = listCards.OrderBy(s => s.DateOfCreation.Date).ToList();
```

Cards, is my Custom Class and it inherits from Panel Object/Class

```
namespace WinFormsApp1
{
    public class Cards : Panel
    {
        public DateTime DateOfCreation { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan TimeOfCreation { get; set; }

        public Cards()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Sorting Cards object works perfectly, however, due to the dynamic functions I use, I have lot of trouble adding some handlers, and would like to sort the API result before adding its data to the Cards Object in my AppForm.

*In Short, I would like to sort the Data stored at **Backups** by **created_at***

Thank you in Advance for any input.

Comment: Why not deserialize to a non-dynamic?

Comment: Because I couldn't, the API result has too much more proprieties than shared above, and Only Dynamic worked for me.

Comment: If you put in the properties you need, it will only fill those. It makes this way easier.

Comment: Unless you have a situation where absolutely need `dynamic`, you should almost always avoid it. It will cause more problems that it solves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer after some research.

Here is an easy way that worked for me:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string json = @"
        [{
            ""bu_region"": ""US"",
            ""created_at"": ""2022-01-04 00:06:09"",
            ""is_automate"": ""0"",
            ""bu_snapshot_name"": ""null"",
            ""plugin_v"": ""4.5.2"",
        },
        {
            ""bu_region"": ""US"",
            ""created_at"": ""2022-02-20 00:07:55"",
            ""is_automate"": ""0"",
            ""bu_snapshot_name"": ""null"",
            ""plugin_v"": ""4.5.2"",
        },
        {
            ""bu_region"": ""US"",
            ""created_at"": ""2021-12-31 00:05:31"",
            ""is_automate"": ""0"",
            ""bu_snapshot_name"": ""null"",
            ""plugin_v"": ""4.5.2"",
        }]";
        
        JArray array = JArray.Parse(json);
        
        JArray sorted = new JArray(array.OrderBy(obj => (DateTime)obj["created_at"]));
        
        Console.WriteLine(sorted.ToString(Formatting.Indented));
    }
}
```

You can test it here:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/4Y96OZ